# Magento Coupon description on invoice

Tags: php, magento, pdf

I want to print the coupon description on the PDF invoice, together with totals.

So I edited my local copy of: Mage/Sales/Model/Order/PDF/Abstract.php

```
protected function insertTotals($page, $source, $orderdata){
    $order = $source->getOrder();
    $totals = $this->_getTotalsList($source);

    //GET THE COUPON CODE AND PRINT
    $discount = $order->getData('coupon_code');       
    $page->drawText($discount, 290, 290, 'UTF-8');
```

I am able to get the coupon_code but not the coupon description. 
Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!